# Filtering image collection using date and lat long from feature collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv

I'm trying to use the JSON data that i have turned in a feature collection using this code:

```
var dict = ee.Dictionary(JSONRAWDATA)
// inspect the dictionary
print(dict)

// make some months
var months = ee.List(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                      'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']);

// make features from each element in the list
var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(dict.get('pings')).map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Dictionary(feat);
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([ee.Number.parse(feat.get('longitude')), ee.Number.parse(feat.get('latitude'))]);
  var getDate = ee.String(feat.get('datetime'));
  var systemDate = ee.Date.parse("dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss aa", getDate).millis();
  return ee.Feature(geom, ee.Dictionary(feat)).set('system:time_start', systemDate);

}))
  // set the other properties of the dictionaries as properties to the collection
feats = ee.FeatureCollection(feats.setMulti(dict.remove(['pings'])));

print(feats);
print(ee.String(feats.get('description')).split(' '))
```

The code generates a feature collection containing a list of pings and its respective date, lat and long.

I need to use this data (date, lat, long) in this code (below) to filter my imagecollection and give me a table with the spectral bands data based on the feature information. This is possible ?

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([67.42467260724823, 21.057842149424154]);

var rrs = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI")
  .filterDate('2018-1-04', '2018-1-05')
  .select('Rrs_488', 'Rrs_531', 'Rrs_547', 'Rrs_555')
  .filterBounds(geometry);

rrs = rrs.toList(rrs.size());

var reduceR = function(image) {
  image = ee.Image(image);
  var reducedVal = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: geometry,
  })
  return ee.Feature(geometry).set(reducedVal);
};

var mRrs=rrs.map(reduceR);
mRrs = ee.FeatureCollection(mRrs);


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: mRrs, 
  description: 'rrs', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'rrs', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV', 
  selectors: ['Rrs_488', 'Rrs_531', 'Rrs_547', 'Rrs_555']
});
```

Expected output: A table with the columns: pings, date, lat, long, rrs_488, rrs_531...

I'm trying with this code but returns a blank table:

```
var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(dict.get('pings')).map(function(feat){
  feat = ee.Dictionary(feat);
  var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([ee.Number.parse(feat.get('longitude')), ee.Number.parse(feat.get('latitude'))]);
  var getDate = ee.String(feat.get('datetime'));
  var systemDate = ee.Date.parse("dd MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss aa", getDate).millis();
  return ee.Feature(geom, ee.Dictionary(feat)).set('system:time_start', systemDate);
}))

var rrs = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI")
    .select('Rrs_488', 'Rrs_531', 'Rrs_547', 'Rrs_555')
  .filterBounds(feats, ee.Filter.stringContains('ping'));

rrs = rrs.toList(rrs.size());

var reduceR = function(image) {
  image = ee.Image(image);
  var reducedVal = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: (feats),
  })
  return ee.Feature(feats).set(reducedVal);
};

var mRrs=rrs.map(reduceR);
mRrs = ee.FeatureCollection(mRrs);


Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: mRrs, 
  description: 'rrs', 
  fileNamePrefix: 'rrs', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV', 
  selectors: ['Rrs_488', 'Rrs_531', 'Rrs_547', 'Rrs_555']
});
```

Comment: The code could use some minor improvements, but the reason you get a blank table is due to the image availability. You should make composites of multiple images or extend the date range to get more ouputs. https://code.earthengine.google.com/fa02f73625c0c4a1c350e626db5efeec

Comment: Thanks, i made what you told me and works, But now the code brings all the data from each point in a large date interval. How do i get the data from each point only in respectively date ? Something like: Date: xx/xx/xxxx Lat: xxxx Long: xxx Rrs_488:xxx ...